# showing the hidden div only on selecting any value from dropdown is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i'm working with php/mysql. i have made a form which have a dropdown list of courses which comes from databse.now i want to show a div on selecting one of my course but its not working somehow.please help me guys.

Here is my code for dropdown:

```
<select name="coursetype" id='coursetype' required>
   <option value="" selected>Select Course Type</option>
   <option  value="UG" <?php if($student['coursetype']=='UG'){ ?> selected <?php }?>>4-Year BA (Hons.) Degree</option>
   <option value="PG" <?php if($student['coursetype']=='PG'){ ?> selected <?php }?>>2-Year PG Diploma</option>
   <option value="PGD" <?php if($student['coursetype']=='PGD'){ ?> selected <?php }?>>1-Year PG Prof. Diploma</option>
    <option value="MA" <?php if($student['coursetype']=='MA'){ ?> selected <?php }?>>2-Year MA Degree</option>
</select>
```

Here is the code for hidden div which i want to open on selecting PG courses the second selection in dropdown.:

```
<div id="PG" class="group">
        <h3>9.  DECLARATION BY APPLICANT</h3>
</div>
```

Please tell me guys how can i achieve it via jquery/javascript??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#coursetype").on('change',function(){
        if($("#coursetype").val() == 'PG')
           $("#PG").show();
        else
            $("#PG").hide();
    });
  });
```

Comment: I would add a `$("#coursetype").change()` call at the end, so the event is automatically triggered when the page is loaded, without any user interaction.

Comment: @Deepu : thanks a ton. what to do if i want to open that div on UG course also.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this-

Iinitially keep PG as hidden and show when dropdown changes

```
$( "#coursetype" ).change(function() {
  if ( $("#coursetype").val() == "PG" )
  {
      $("#PG").show();
  }
  else
  {
      $("#PG").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use js

for display your element

```
document.getElementById('your_element_id').style.display='block';
```

and

for hide your element

```
document.getElementById('your_element_id').style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("document").ready(function(){
       $("#PG").hide();
 $("#coursetype").change(function() {
    if( $(this).val()=="PG"){
         $("#PG").show();
      }else{
           $("#PG").hide();
      }

 }).trigger( "change" );
 });
```